# Script Error under Dash

Tags: scripts

Why the following script is giving me a error by using Dash (sh) and the same is working by using Bash?

I cannot see the error

Thanks for your help.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Calculate the length of the hypotenuse of a Pythagorean triangle
# using hypotenuse^2 = adjacent^2 + opposite^2

echo -n "Enter the Adjacent length: "
read adjacent

echo -n "Enter the Opposite length: "
read opposite

asquared=$(($adjacent ** 2))        # get a^2
osquared=$(($opposite ** 2))        # get o^2

hsquared=$(($osquared + $asquared)) # h^2 = a^2 + o^2

hypotenuse=`echo "scale=3;sqrt ($hsquared)"  | bc`  # bc does sqrt

echo "The Hypotenuse is $hypotenuse"
```

The result:

```
myname@myhost:~$ sh ./hypotenusa.sh

Enter the Adjacent length: 12

Enter the Opposite length: 4

./hypotenusa.sh: 12: ./hypotenusa.sh: arithmetic expression: expecting primary: "12 ** 2"


myname@myhost:~$ bash ./hypotenusa.sh

Enter the Adjacent length: 12

Enter the Opposite length: 4

The Hypotenuse is 12.649
```

My Ubuntu version is 13.04.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simply that `dash` does not support exponentiation via the `**` operator (it is not a requirement for a POSIX-compliant shell interpreter).

You can check if a particular script uses such 'bashisms' using the `checkbashisms` utility, e.g.

```
$ cat > myscript.sh
#!/bin/sh

echo $((12 ** 2))
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>

```
$ checkbashisms myscript.sh
possible bashism in myscript.sh line 3 (exponentiation is not POSIX):
echo $((12 ** 2))
$
```

Answer (score 0):

`**` operator is not recognized by sh. sh (Shell Command Language) is a programming language described by the [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html), while bash change the behavior of valid POSIX shell scripts, so by itself bash is not a valid POSIX shell. `**` exponentiation operator was introduced in bash once with version 2.02.

Sources:

- [Difference between sh and bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash)
- [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide - Operators](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ops.html)

In bash and in sh `^` is the default operator for raising a number to another (see `man bc`). So, your script should like:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# Calculate the length of the hypotenuse of a Pythagorean triangle
# using hypotenuse^2 = adjacent^2 + opposite^2

echo -n "Enter the Adjacent length: "
read adjacent

echo -n "Enter the Opposite length: "
read opposite

asquared="($adjacent ^ 2)"        # get a^2
osquared="($opposite ^ 2)"        # get o^2

hsquared="($osquared + $asquared)" # h^2 = a^2 + o^2

hypotenuse=`echo "scale=3;sqrt ($hsquared)"  | bc`  # bc does sqrt

echo "The Hypotenuse is $hypotenuse"
```